# Can not line break on label

Tags: ios, objective-c, label, line-breaks

I want to set line break on my label.

I have tried:

```
self.lblYouHaveAMatch.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.lblYouHaveAMatch.numberOfLines = 0;
```

I have a string like this:

```
"You have a match with \nfirst_name!"
```

I also try `"\r"` instead of `"\n"` but it doesn't work.

My label on interface builder.

[image]

[image]

But it only show `"You have a match with"` on my device.

Comment: have you tried like this `label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \r %@",@"first line",@"seconcd line"];`

Comment: Try with increasing your UILabel height.

Comment: Try to using `attributed` text instead of `plain` text

Comment: @Aneesh, I've already tried, not work.

Comment: use textview instead of label

Comment: @Manishankar, I don't set autolayout for that label, please check my image update.

Comment: Agree with Manishankar. u need to make your label frame taller (in storyboard)

Comment: If you're just trying to separate `"You have a match with"` from a name , you can try to add a width constraint to the label , so that one line can only hold "You have a match with" , this will force the label to expand in height when its content is longer than "You have a match with".

Comment: Change height to 50

Comment: I think you need to change the frame of label after setting test if you are not using autolayout.

Comment: Change height to 56 work for me :). Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You are using autoresising mask, on your last image
you need to choose in autoresicing : right border 
too (because now you have only top and left border
. And you need to select a horizontal line
So after that you will set horizontal borders but you 
will not set height , so you height will be set automatically 
because use specify number of lines 0

Answer (score 1):

Here you just need to calculate the hight of label based on given text and width.

```
NSString *sampleMultiLineText=@"1  Showing First Line\n2 Showing Second line\n3 Showing Third line";


NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: self.lbMultiLine.font};

// ios7.0
CGRect adjustedSize = [sampleMultiLineText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.lbMultiLine.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:attributes
                                          context:nil];

// 0 = Multiple lines
self.lbMultiLine.numberOfLines = 0;
self.lbMultiLine.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

//setting text
self.lbMultiLine.text = sampleMultiLineText;


//now Update Frame as hight of label may be higher than current so all the text can be show
[self.lbMultiLine setFrame:CGRectMake(self.lbMultiLine.frame.origin.x, self.lbMultiLine.frame.origin.y,adjustedSize.size.width,adjustedSize.size.height)];
```